# How do I start streaming immediately after I started Jitsi API?

Tags: javascript, angular, jitsi

I have a Jitsi instance running in one of the pages of my Angular application. It works flawlessly.

Now I want a stream to start as soon as the API is initialized. I couldn't find any onLoad or onStart event of the API. So initially I tried this way:

```
this.api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI("mydomain.com", this.options);
this.api.executeCommand('startRecording', {
        mode: 'stream', 
        rtmpStreamKey: "MyKey",
        rtmpBroadcastID: "MyId"
})
```

And it didn't work. After some fruitless search I've made it work moving execute command to a function and doing:

```
setTimeout(()=>this.startStream(), 10000);
```

But that's ugly and error-prone as hell. I imagine it should exist a better way .

How do I know that the API is fully initialized so I can start live stream ?

**Edit**

I tried onload event on API creation but it works only sometimes. Others it just ignores the command.

Comment: there is the `onload: The IFrame onload event handler.` option maybe? or perhaps one of the documented [events](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe-events) can help determine when it's good to go?

Comment: See the edit I made

Comment: and the events? did you try using those?

Comment: What event ? No event besides onload is related to initializing the API

Comment: having same issue just added timeout to 10s but still sometimes api is not initialized

Comment: @babbintandukar I have the same problem and still looking for a viable solution. In my case I disabled the auto-start of the stream.